# Retain rows in same group if any pass filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
 df <- data.frame(sample = c("R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R3"), event = c(1, 10, 10, 20, 3, 3), name = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'baz'))
```

And I want to select rows grouped by `sample` and `event` where any of the rows in this group have a `name == 'baz'`.

The desired output:

```
  sample event name
2     R2    10  bar # another row in same sample, event group has name == 'baz' 
3     R2    10  baz
4     R2    20  baz
5     R3     3  foo # another row with same sample, event group has name == 'baz' 
6     R3     3  baz
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
  df %>% 
    group_by(sample, event) %>% 
    filter(name == 'baz')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `any()`!

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sample, event) %>%
  filter(any(name == "baz"))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   sample, event [3]
  sample event name 
  <fct>  <dbl> <fct>
1 R2        10 bar  
2 R2        10 baz  
3 R2        20 baz  
4 R3         3 foo  
5 R3         3 baz
```

Comment: better: `any(name %in% 'baz')`

Comment: @erocar - beautiful!